# Jersey invoking sub resource wrongly

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, exceptionmapper

I am learning RESTful web services using JAX-RS.
I have a `MessageResource` and a sub resource `CommentResource`.

In my `MessageResource` I mapped comment sub resource with test method, which I commented in the `MessageResource` class because I don't want `CommentResource` to be invoked.

```
package org.kaushik.javabrains.messenger.resource;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.Uri;
import org.kaushik.javabrains.messenger.exception.DataNotFoundException;
import org.kaushik.javabrains.messenger.model.Message;
import org.kaushik.javabrains.messenger.services.MessageService;

@Path("/messages")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MessageResource {

    public MessageResource() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @GET
    public List<Message> getAllMessage() {

        MessageService obj = new MessageService();
        return obj.getAllMessages();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    public Message getMessageById(@PathParam("messageId") String messageId) {

        MessageService obj = new MessageService();
        Message retrivedMessage = obj.getMessage(Long.parseLong(messageId));
        return retrivedMessage;
    }

    /*
     * This method is used to add new message in database returns created
     * message with generated id
     */
    /*
     * @POST public Message postMessage(Message msg){
     * 
     * MessageService obj = new MessageService(); msg = obj.addMessage(msg);
     * 
     * return msg; }
     */

    /**
     * This method created the new message and sends new message with 201 status
     * code using Response
     * 
     * @param msg
     * @return
     */
    @POST
    public Response postMessage(Message msg, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        MessageService obj = new MessageService();
        msg = obj.addMessage(msg);
        // This is to send only created status
        // return Response.status(Status.CREATED).entity(msg).build();

        // If we want to send status + new created resource path

        String newId = msg.getId() + "";
        URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(newId).build();
        return Response.created(uri).entity(msg).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    public Message updateMessage(Message msg, @PathParam("messageId") long id) {

        MessageService obj = new MessageService();
        msg.setId(id);
        msg = obj.updateMessage(msg);

        return msg;
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    public void deleteMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long id) {

        MessageService obj = new MessageService();
        obj.removeMessage(id);
    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked if url asked for comments irrespective of http
     * method, it will invoke the CommentResource which is a sub resouce of
     * Message
     * 
     * @return
     */
    /*
     * @Path("/{messageId}/comments") public CommentResource test() { return new
     * CommentResource(); }
     */
}
```

I am having sub resource `CommentResource` as following:

```
package org.kaushik.javabrains.messenger.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("/")
public class CommentResource {

    public CommentResource() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @GET
    public String test() {

        return "new sub resource";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{commentId}")
    public String getCommentById(@PathParam("messageId") String messageId, @PathParam("commentId") String commentId) {

        return commentId + " This is dummy comment for messageID=" + messageId;
    }

}
```

I created a generic exception mapper, which is mapped to `Throwable` class.
It is created for the purpose, if any exception happens at server end, rather displaying Tomcat error report page, meaningful message should be sent.

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("in Genereic mapper");
        ErrorMessage message = new ErrorMessage(ex.getMessage(),"/Messenger/documentation",500);
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(message).build();
    }
}
```

Further, when I am testing my generic exception mapper by invoking a url

> http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messa

which is not mapped to any method in `MessageResource`. It is invoking the `CommentResource`  following method:

```
@GET
@Path("/{commentId}")
public String getCommentById(@PathParam("messageId") String messageId, @PathParam("commentId") String commentId) {

    return commentId + " This is dummy comment for messageID=" + messageId;
}
```

If I comment the above method I am getting proper response in Postman.

Can anybody explain this behavior. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `@Path("/")` from the `CommentResource`.  It is being added as a root resource. So when you access `/mesa`, the `CommentResource` is mapped to `/`, and it hits the resource method mapped to `@Path("{whatever}")`.

Sub resource locator classes should not have `@Path`. That is only for root resource classes. In a sub-resource locator request, it will be ignored, but on app startup, it is still registered like a regular root resource.

Comment: Means comment resource is not working as a sub resource rather than it is working as independent resource??

Comment: With or without `@Path("/")` it will still work as a subresource class, but the `@Path` is ignored. Like I said, subresource classes should not be annotated with `@Path`. With it,  it will be mapped to `/`. If you don't want that, then remove the `@Path("/")`

Comment: ya, its working even after removing the @Path from comment resource.